# one connection multiple requests Rest Service

Tags: c#, web-services, httpwebrequest, connection-pooling

How can one issue multiple requests using the same service?

I have created a static httpWebRequest:

```
    private static HttpWebRequest request;
    //private static StreamReader streamReader;
    //private StreamWriter streamWriter;

    public CentralRestService2(LogFile log)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("service address");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Accept = "*/*";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "username and password";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
         }

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string body = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(emailRequest);
            streamWriter.Write(body);

        }

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        response.Close();
     }
```

I get error messages including that the stream cannot be written to. The connection has unexpectedly closed. I can't seem to find the answer anywhere!

Comment: using disposes the steam, try it without the using and just close them manually when done.

Comment: @Jacobr365, not sure that'll work in this case. The request stream should be a forward-only/write-only stream, just as the response stream is a forward-only/read-only stream. Only good for one use. The entire concept of REST is that a request/response pair is completely self-contained and stand alone.

Comment: Is there some way to use one open connection for all the requests? I also tried that Jacob - it doesn't work either - it creates the connection closed message.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create static `HttpWebRequest`.
Request does not represent a connection, but it uses [ServicePointManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) which manages underlying TCP connections for you.
Just create a new instance of `HttpWebRequest` every time you need to send a request.

UPDATE:
If you want to create a client for your service, you should use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) instead:

```
// add reference to System.Net.Http and System.Net.Http.Formatting
using System.Net.Http;

// with a handler you can configure the client and its behavior
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("service address");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "username and password");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(httpClient.BaseAddress, emailRequest);
```

Comment: it seems HttpClient can not handle GET requests with no body but content type set. HttpWebRequest can

Comment: `HttpClient` uses the `HttpWebRequest` under the hood - should yield identical results